# Practice Makes Perfect factorial

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am taking Codecademy lessons required by my teacher. The instructions read, Define a function factorial that takes an integer x as input.

Calculate and return the factorial of that number.

For my code, I put,

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 1:
        return factorial('n' - 1)
```

When I clicked save and submit code, it gave me this error message,

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I tried looking at the codecademy Q and A forum, but I didn't find anything feasible. I even went on this site and looked up what the error message meant. I looked at the hint provided by codecademy and it just made me more confused! Please help. Any feedback/ advice is always helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `'n'`? First of all, that is a `String`, not a reference to the variable `n`. Also, (if my previous statement is true) you take the integer `x` as input, not `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract the number `1` from the letter `n`.  Instead you should subtract `1` from the number you were given.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string `'n'` in to your factorial method. There are two problems with this:

1) You cannot perform a subtraction operation by trying to do `'n'` - 1 (string type - int type).

2) You most likely meant to pass `x` instead of `'n'`.

Next, your recursive algorithm for checking a factorial is incorrect.

You need to take the number, multiplied by the return of calling the factorial method again, but passing the number subtracted by 1. But then you need your "exit" condition, which is when the number reaches a value below 1:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial(x - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are trying to make a factorial function using recursion. Your code has a few problems:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 1:
        return factorial('n' - 1)
```

First of all, on line 3 you are trying to subtract `'n'` (a String) from `1` (an Integer). Remove the quotes to fix this.

Secondly, (if my previous statement was correct) your function takes input as `x`, not `n`. You are probably trying to do:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 1:
        return factorial(x - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you are trying to manipulate two things of different types, integer and string. Ans also it seems that your function "factorial" will only work if you give it an integer number 1. You can simply do this with while loop; (keep in mind the TYPES of things you want to manipulate).

```
def factorial(x):
  n=1
  total = x
  last_int = x
  while n < total:
     x = x * (last_int-1)
     n += 1
     last_int -= 1
  return x     


if __name__ == "__main__":
  while 1:
    number = raw_input("enter number: ")
    result = factorial(int(number))       
    print 'factorial number for ' + str(number) + ' is ' + str(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also another way to fix the task. You can use range with a negative step -1 and multiply from x to 1:

```
def factorial (x):
    total = 1
    if x < 1:
        return total
    else:
        for i in range(x, 0, -1):
        total *= i
    return total
```